# Group inbox mail in Thunderbird (like Office 360)

Tags: thunderbird

I am looking for a way to make Thunderbird group together mails by day (date) like Outlook does.

Right now it is just one long feed with no breaks between days.

[Here is a screenshot](https://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSImages/Image_Outlook_KnowWhatsHappening_430x315.jpg?version=72cad766-6e5d-8032-9bab-d2508f99c348) - see how it is organised by date (today, Monday etc.).

Does anyone know of a plugin that will do this in Thunderbird?